# Concatenate list of column names and fill values up in Power Query

Tags: powerquery

Have the following M code where I'm changing 0 values to null (thanks to another user for the help) but am now wanting to fill up because every row has inconsistent data and I want all of the data to be on the top two rows.

I'm now attempting to create a list of column names and stuff it in to Table.FillUp but am getting an expression error that lists the columns and the syntax ("ColumnXXX",) syntax but reads that the columns "of the table" weren't found.

Sample image below of what I"m trying to accomplish.  Ideally, all values would move to the first row and null values would be removed.

```
    Custom1 = Table.ColumnNames(#"Transposed Table2"),
Custom2 = List.Transform(Custom1, each {_, each if _ = 0 then null else _}),
Custom3 = Table.TransformColumns(#"Transposed Table2",Custom2),
Custom4 = """"&Text.Combine(Table.ColumnNames(Custom3),""", """)&"""",
Custom5 = Table.FillUp(Custom3,{Custom4})
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Figured out a better way.  Rather than filling up, remove the null values and shift the data up.  Solution below.

```
Custom1 = Table.ColumnNames(#"Transposed Table2"),
Custom2 = List.Transform(Custom1, each {_, each if _ = 0 then null else _}),
Custom3 = Table.TransformColumns(#"Transposed Table2",Custom2),
#"Added Custom" = Table.FromColumns(List.Transform(Table.ToColumns(Custom3), List.RemoveNulls),Table.ColumnNames(Custom3))
```